# Removing child-parent association in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Consider the following domain classes

```
class Business{
    static hasMany = [contacts:ContactPerson]
}

class ContactPerson{
}
```

Given the following domain classes, say we use the following examples:

> Alice is ACME's contact person. Bob and Carol are Calamity Corp's contact person.

Say I wanted to remove Bob in the ContactPerson table.  Thus:

```
bob.delete(flush:true)
```

But the code will result to the server complaining about contraints:

```
ERROR: update or delete on table "contact_person" violates foreign key constraint
    "fk4a69c6b329ef2fe1" on table "business_contact_person"
Detail: Key (id)=(174) is still referenced from table "business_contact_person".
```

In this context, the exception is thrown because Bob is still associated with Calamity Corp.

**How do I delete Bob from the ContactPerson table?** I wanted to remove Bob from the database altogether.  I don't want to add belongsTo since I don't want to cascade the delete to Business' children (that is to say, if I delete Acme Corp from the database, I still want Alice to be in the system).

I've seen examples on [disassociating the parent from the child](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/)  but not the other way around.

Comment: shouldn't {contacts:ContactPerson} be [contacts:ContactPerson]?

Comment: You pretty much have two choices -- add belongsTo (which you say you don't want to do) or disassociate the parent from the child first. Why do you want to keep Alice if her company is deleted? Perhaps the model needs to be represented differently? (Like a join table of business to contact)

Comment: changed the curly braces to square ones.  Thanks, aldrin.  Now, for the question why I needed to keep Alice.  Well, I wanted to keep a directory of businesses and contact persons.  So even if ACME is no longer in the database, I'd still want Alice to be in it (probably Alice moved to another company and I wanted to associate it with another company).  Or say the Bob has moved to another company which is not in the database so I wanted to delete him in the ContactPerson table.

Comment: Todd mentioned disassociating the parent from the child.  In this case, how would I do that?  Using the GORM, Alice does not have any idea she's connected with a Acme.  Would it be a safe design to have a bidirectional flow from ContactPerson to Business?  What if I add another person, Doug, and he's not associated with any Businesses?  Would it be practical to create a pseudo-company in the database just to satisfy the association?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.  So with a little more digging, I finally got the codes that I wanted.  John Rellis' post on [Relationship Advice : Grails One-To-Many](http://johnrellis.blogspot.com/2010/05/relationship-advice-grails-one-to-many.html) was especially helpful.  In this article, he mentions how to query from children to parent (which is exactly what I am looking for).

Going back to the question, I wanted to remove Bob from the ContactPerson table but given the relationship between Business and ContactPerson simply calling bob.delete() simply would not do.  What I need is to look for all businesses associated with Bob and remove the association.  Thus the code below:

```
def bob = ContactPerson.get(params.id)

def criteria = Business.createCriteria()

def businesses = criteria.listDistinct{
    createAlias("contactPersons","c")
    eq("c.id", bob.id)
}

businesses.each{business->
    business.removeFromContactPersons(bob)
    business.save(flush:true)
}

bob.delete(flush:true)
```

I also added a new mapping to the Business domain model:

```
static mapping = {
    children cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe by simply adding a `belongsTo`, the cascade should work as expected...

```
class Business{
  static hasMany = [ contacts:ContactPerson ]
}

class ContactPerson{
  static belongsTo = [ business: Business ]
}
```

Comment: So simple :).  Thanks!